# Error linking c++ shared library with CUDA

Tags: cuda, g++, shared-libraries, nvcc, .so

EDIT:

I was able to reduce the problem a lot. Only three files, one .cpp, one .cu and one heather, and the same error as the original message appears when trying to link them.

The code of example files is very very simple:

example.cpp

```
#include "example.h"

extern "C" void launch_kernels();

void example::launch()
{

    launch_kernels();

}
```

example_kernel.cu

```
#include <iostream>

__global__ void Find()
{}

extern "C" void launch_kernels() {

    std::cout << "Hello\n" << std::endl;

}
```

example.h

```
class example {

public:
    void launch();
};
```

Compiling...

```
 g++ -shared -fPIC -Wall -O3 -c example.cpp -o example.o
```

```
nvcc -shared -c -O3 example_kernel.cu -o example_kernel.o --expt-relaxed-constexpr --extended-lambda
```

And I get two .o files without problems. But, in the last step:

```
nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC -shared example_kernel.o example.o -o example.a
```

I get the fatal original error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: example_kernel.o: warning: relocation against `_ZNKSt5ctypeIcE8do_widenEc' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: example_kernel.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_Z4Findv' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

ORIGINAL:

I have a big shared library written in C++, and now, I want to pass a part of code to CUDA, the situation is:

I have four `.cpp` files and one `.cu` file. I have the line `extern “C” void launch_kernels()` in one `.cpp` file and in the CUDA file in order to link them.
The `.cu` file compiles without problems with nvcc to the `.o` file, as same as `.cpp` files separately with these arguments:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -m64 -pthread -DWM_DP -DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32 -Wall -Wextra -Wold-style-cast -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-attributes -Wno-unknown-pragmas -O3 -DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -fPIC -Wno-old-style-cast -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fpermissive -I/usr/include -fPIC -c file1.c -o file1.o
```

Then, I build a shared library `.so` with these four `.o` without problems:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -m64 -pthread -DWM_DP -DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32 -Wall -Wextra -Wold-style-cast -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-attributes -Wno-unknown-pragmas -O3 -DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -fPIC -Wno-old-style-cast -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fpermissive -I/usr/include -fPIC -shared -Xlinker --add-needed -Xlinker --no-as-needed file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o -o finallib.so
```

The problem is in the last step, when I want to link my cuda file with this `finallib.so`. I tried with nvcc:

```
nvcc --shared -Xcompiler -fPIC finallib.so filecuda.cu -o finallibcuda.so --expt-relaxed-constexpr --extended-lambda
```

And I only get a very small file that doesn't work. Then I tried with g++:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -m64 -pthread -DWM_DP -DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32 -Wall -Wextra -Wold-style-cast -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-attributes -Wno-unknown-pragmas -O3 -DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -fPIC -Wno-old-style-cast -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-deprecated-declarations -fpermissive -fPIC -shared -Xlinker --add-needed -Xlinker --no-as-needed finallib.so filecuda.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart -o finallibcuda.so
```

And I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: filecuda.o: warning: relocation against _Z4Findv' in read-only section .text.startup’ /usr/bin/ld: filecuda.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_Z4Findv’ can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
```

And I also tried linking `.o` and `.cu` before the creation of the final `.so` file and this linked fine, but I get the same error when I try to create the final `.so`.

Any idea?

Comment: If you want a shared library, you should call it `.so` instead of `.a`.

Comment: The problem is that the `nvcc` compile command does not specify `-Xcompiler=-fPIC`. Your link command works for me if I use `nvcc -shared -c -O3 -Xcompiler=-fPIC example_kernel.cu -o example_kernel.o --expt-relaxed-constexpr --extended-lambda`.

Comment: Thanks @paleonix I was finally able to compile it.

Answer (score 3):

This command:

```
nvcc -shared -c -O3 example_kernel.cu -o example_kernel.o --expt-relaxed-constexpr --extended-lambda
```

does *not* pass `-fPIC` to the compiler. It also passes useless `-shared` flag (which is used only during linking, but no linking is happening here).

Correct command should look something like:

```
nvcc -Xcompiler -fPIC -c -O3 example_kernel.cu -o example_kernel.o --expt-relaxed-constexpr --extended-lambda
```